# Do something after var reaches certain value with setinterval?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, timer, setinterval

I have a bootstrap loading bar that updates with setinterval every 250ms so it looks like it's making progress. I am trying to show an alert and redirect when the loading bar reaches 100%.

```
<div class="progress" style="border-radius:0px;">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" 
         style="border-radius:0px;" id="loading" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" 
         aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">
   </div>
</div>
```

I've tried adding `window.location` before the end of the function but it does not work. How can I do this? Maybe with an if statement?

```
        var percentl = 10;
        setInterval(function () {
            percentl = percentl + 2;
            document.getElementById("loading").style.width = percentl + "%";
        }, 250);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop timer using `clearInterval`, add `if` statement to check if % has reached to 100 and `location.href` for redirecting URL.

```
var percentl = 10;
var timer = setInterval(function () {
              percentl = percentl + 2;
              document.getElementById("loading").style.width = percentl + "%";
              if(percentl > 99){
                clearInterval(timer);
                // do your stuff
                location.href = "redirectToThisURL";
              }              
            }, 250);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need an if statement to check whether the bar is full, and if so, clear the interval, show the alert and finally do the redirection.

Useful functions:

- [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval)
- [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)